# How to set a click in center of RelativeLayout after load Activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like know how can I set a click in center of an `RelativeLayout` after Activity load ?

Comment: try placing an empty view with centerInParent params and add a clickListener to it.

Comment: Share your code so we can help you

Comment: `javascript` - are you sure??

Comment: @VladMatvienko sry.. im newbie.. i dont know how to do it.

Comment: See the answer to the question. It is correct, but not detailed enough.

Comment: @Raykud isn't not a native button.. is a parse button via Jsoup... i need do an click via position.. in RelativeLayout center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use `gravity` center in `RelativeLayout` and place clickable element in `RelativeLayout`

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/the_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Centered Button"/>
   ```
2. use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in clickable element inside the `RelativeLayout`

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/the_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Centered Button"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
   ```

Comment: this would become a good answer if you add some code sample. I encourage you to do that.

Comment: @Atam_Jeet ... thx for u answer... But I need to simulate a manual click .. cuz isn't a native button

Comment: i dnt understant what you want exactly, but i thik u wnat :- 1) click anywhere in relative layout :- you can add onclick listener in relative layout 2) click in center of relative layout in particular area :- you can make button transparent

Comment: @Atam_JeetSingh I want to simulate a TouchScreen inside of a RelativeLayout

Comment: you can use watermark as touchable objects, the two ways i wrote above are methods to make an object in center, now this object can be transparent or an watermark object that can be listened on click, now its up to you how much area you want to make clickable, increase size of object relatively, still if you have some problem  show a pencil sketch of your requirement